# solution of poisson problem with finite element method in 1D

Tags: dirac-delta, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

[image][image]I am going to solve 
$$-u''=-1-10\delta (x-0.2)$$
$$u(0)=u(1)=0$$
by finite element method in 1D.
The exact solution that I got is
$$u(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {\frac{{{x^2}}}{2} - \frac{{17}}{2}x~~~~~~~~~~if~~~x \in [0,0.2]}  \\
   {\frac{{{x^2}}}{2} + \frac{3}{2}x - 2~~~~~if ~~~~x \in [0.2,1]}  \\
\end{array}} \right.$$
and I put $f(x)=-1-10*dirac(x-0.2)$ in my matlab code.
The problem is the solution of the finite element problem is exactly the same as of the solution of equation $-u''=-1$.

Comment: You have to make sure that one of the nodes is at $x=0.2$

Comment: Yes, it is. I put $h=0.1$. but the result is like $u=x^2/2-x/2$ which is the exact solution of $-u''=-1$.

Comment: And what is the value of the r.h.s of your equation when you evaluate $x = 0.2$?

Comment: -0.1 It seems that matlab does not consider the dirac delta function.

Comment: Probably is best if you add the code to your posting

Comment: IT is a good idea. How can I put the code which is looks like matlab code here?

Comment: Just copy/paste it, make sure to tab each line so the platform properly formats the code

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Your algorithm is not going to handle very well the $\delta(x)$ distribution. Just try and output $f(0.2)$ so you can see the problem. My advise is to change your definition of $f = e^{-(x-0.2)^2/2\sigma^2}/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$ with $\sigma \approx 0.1 h$

Comment: Thanks, the result is better but it still has the error when I use the smaller h, the error increased. $\sigma$ is always equal $0.1h$?

Comment: The idea is to decrease $\sigma$ as much as possible $\delta(x-0.2) = \lim _{\sigma \to 0}f(x)$, however you cannot decrease too much because then your grid is not going to pick it. Make sure you always include $x=0.2$ in your nodes, regardless of $h$!

Comment: Is there any way to change $\sigma$ to get the better approximation of dirac function? Because I still have an error.

Comment: Could you please send me a plot of $f(x)$ in the cases where you get an error? make sure to mark the points $x_i$ you used to calculate the finite differences

Comment: Just upload them to your question

Comment: The result is for h=0.1.

Comment: Great! Thanks, can you try now with $h = 0.001$?

Comment: Red is the exact solution.

Comment: And if you reduce $\sigma$ to $0.01h$?

Comment: I put $\sigma=0.25h$ and it works better. Thank you so much. It is the first plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement Dirac loading for linear elements is to simply put a node at $x=0.2$ and add $-10$ to your load vector at the respective slot.

Here is an example code using Python, NumPy and spfem, see last 8 lines or so. You can easily do the same thing in Matlab.

```
from spfem.mesh import MeshLine                                                          
from spfem.assembly import AssemblerElement                                              
from spfem.element import ElementLineP1                                                  
from spfem.utils import direct                                                           
import numpy as np                                                                       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                          

# build mesh                                                                             
p=np.arange(0,1.2,0.2)                                                                   
t=np.arange(0,len(p)-1)                                                                  
t=np.vstack((t,t+1))                                                                     
m=MeshLine(np.array([p]),t)                                                              
m.refine(4)                                                                              

# assemble stiffness matrix and load vector                                             
a=AssemblerElement(m,ElementLineP1())                                                    
A=a.iasm(lambda du,dv: du*dv)                                                            
f=a.iasm(lambda v:-1*v)                                                                  

# boundary dofs                                                                          
B=np.array([0,len(p)-1])                                                                 
# interior dofs                                                                          
I=np.setdiff1d(np.arange(m.p.shape[1]),B)                                                

# add -10 to load vector element corresponding to x=0.2                                                               
f0=0*f                                                                                   
f0[1]=-10                                                                                

# solve system                                                                           
x=direct(A,f+f0,I=I)                                                                     

m.plot(x)                                                                                
m.show()
```

The solution looks like this:

[image]

The rationale for this is the following. The load vector corresponds to the linear form

$$-\int_0^1 v \,dx - \int_0^1 10 \delta(x-0.2) v \,dx = -\int_0^1 v\,dx - 10 v(0.2).$$

If you put $i$'th node at $x=0.2$ then the $i$'th element of the load vector is

$$f_i = -\int_0^1 \phi_i \,dx - 10.$$

Thus, the contribution from the Dirac loading is just $-10$.